# Any solution to autofix or autocorrect ESLint rules?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, eslint

I have implemented a new set of ESLint rules to an existing Javasript-React project and need to fix around 7000 lint errors.  Is there any solution available to auto fix or autocorrect Linting rules like below

```
  ✖  18:47  A space is required before '}'    object-curly-spacing
  ✖  19:10  A space is required after '{'     object-curly-spacing
  ✖  21:14  Missing trailing comma            comma-dangle
  ✖  129:9  Expected newline before return statement  newline-before-return
  ✖  133:2  Missing semicolon                 semi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `eslint` with the `--fix` flag it will try to fix any linting changes that it can, and let you know which ones it cannot. See the documentation here: http://eslint.org/blog/2015/09/eslint-v1.5.0-released

Comment: Another way to check which rules are fixable is to look for the little wrench icon next to the rule name in the official docs: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/